# How to wire up the XP Power 8-pin isolated DC-DC converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, wiring, isolation

I want to use the XP Power IEU0312S12 12V DC-DC converter but can't see how I should wire this.

1. What do they mean with "Single" and "Dual" ?
2. Can I put 12V on Pin 1 and 4 and then get the output on Pin 5 and 7 without connecting any external component or doing something else, is that it ?
3. What do they mean with "Common" ?

[image]

The datasheet can be found [here](http://www.xppower.com/Portals/0/pdfs/SF_IEU03.pdf)

Comment: Please use official mfg link, not some sketchy datasheet repo, i believe it is http://www.xppower.com/Portals/0/pdfs/SF_IEU03.pdf

Comment: Note the output has a "Maximum
capacitive load" listed in the datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That series of DC-DC converters is available as both single output and dual (+ and -) output versions.

The IEU0312S12 has a single 12 volt output, so you use the "Single" column in the pin connection table.

You should apply the input voltage to pin 1 (negative) and pin 4 (positive).  Take the output from pin 5 (positive) and pin 7 (negative).

For the dual output versions, "Common" is the "zero volt" point between the + and - outputs.

Comment: Number 3. part with "Common" isn't entirely clear, you mean I can use that pin as "zero-volt" point ? Thank you, great answer btw

Comment: On your single-output version, Pin 6 - Common apparently does not exist - it is only there on the dual output versions.